# How to filter keys in AWS using prefix or delimiter on ListObjectsV2Request?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pattern-matching

I have the following options for keys:

```
cat/dog/<random_value>/ShortMetadata
cat/dog/<random_value>/bird/LongMetadata
cat/dog/<random_value>/values
cat/dog/bird/frog
cat/dog/<random_value>/bird/<random_value>/HalfMetadata
```

I want to filter only the metadatas -> ShortMetadata, LongMetadata and HalfMetadata.
Can't figure out how to do it in a nice way using pattern matches.
I looked at the options given on `ListObjectsV2Request` but saw that I can use only `.prefix` or `.delimiter` (I think that i'm looking for is suffix..)

something to look like :

```
ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(Pattern.compile("*/*Metadata"));
```

or:

```
ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix("cat/dog/" + "*" + "Metadata"));
```

Can someone please advise what do to?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in saying that you need a mechanism to filter out keys based on suffix.

Unfortunately that's not possible in S3 as of today. You have following options

**Option 1**

Put some sort of suffix to Metadata objects. Maybe as follows

```
cat/dog/Metadata/<random_value>/ShortMetadata 
cat/dog/Metadata/<random_value>/bird/LongMetadata
```

Here you can search with the prefix `cat/dog/Metadata`. But the feasibility of this option would entirely depend on your program logic

**Option 2**

if you need that information frequently, you can store the keys in some sort of persistence (RDBMS or DynamoDB)

**Option 3**

If the number of objects that you will be sorting isn't a large one then obviously you can list out the entire set of keys and filter out what you need. But this won't be a scaleable and performant option