# How to use Request Prefix to search for file names containing a specific substring

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I was trying to get al the files in S3 where the file name contains a specific substring without looping through millions of file in a data lake.

The files are stored in the S3 bucket with the following structure:

subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolderwith_date_20200514/Logger_20200514172109_109202.xml
subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolderwith_date_20200514/Logger_20200514172109_118960.xml
subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolderwith_date_20200514/Logger_20200514172109_118961.xml
subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolderwith_date_20200514/Logger_20200514172109_118962.xml
subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolderwith_date_20200514/Logger_20200514172109_118967.xml

I was trying to use the delimiter to get only the files where the file name contains the substring "Logger_20200514172109"

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private const string bucketName = "datalake";
    private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.EUWest1;
    private static IAmazonS3 client;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        client = new AmazonS3Client("", "", bucketRegion);

        try
        {
            var request = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Prefix = "subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/subfolderwith_date_20200514/Logger_20200514172109*.xml",
                Delimiter = "",
                MaxKeys = 100
                
            };

            var response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
            var count = 0;
            foreach (S3Object obj in response.S3Objects)
            {
                count++;
                fileList.Add(obj.Key, obj.Size.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("objects" + count.ToString());

          
            await using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"c:\db\myfile.txt"))
            {
                file.WriteLine("List of files" + fileList.Count.ToString()) ;
                foreach (var entry in fileList)
                {
                    file.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("S3 error occurred. Exception: " + amazonS3Exception.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I tried different combinations, but I am not getting anywhere with my attempts.

Comment: I don't imagine you can. It's called "prefix", indicating that it expects the value the string starts with, as opposed to an arbitrary string that exists somewhere in the filename.

Comment: sorry. I edited my request. The substring is the following "Logger_20200514172109"

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51881358/how-to-filter-keys-in-aws-using-prefix-or-delimiter-on-listobjectsv2request).

Comment: thanks John. It's a great suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.  Here's what *prefix* matches actually mean, inside S3, in pseudocode:

```
if (left(object_key,length(prefix)) == prefix) { // this is a match
```

There are no wildcard globbing (e.g. `*` or `?`) or regular expression capabilities in prefix handling.  A prefix is a literal string prefix.

You will have to loop through the millions of files.

You might find [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) useful so that you could download the entire list of object keys and then filter it locally.

Or handle the iteration through the list of object keys separately from the processing of each object -- in classical (non-async) terms, two threads with a queue between them and a semaphore to keep the queue from growing too quickly if the iterator thread gets too far ahead of the processor thread.